# What do I add to this code so that it reads every email?

Tags: python, email

I have some code that reads the oldest email from my gmail account, but I want it to read every email. I am very new to python, I started learning it last week. I have a lot of experience with c++ so I know what loops are I just need help implementing it in python.

What my code does is read the oldest email, then creates an int to hold the number in the subject and then gets a random number from 1 to 10 and prints whether the number in the subject in the email is equal to the random number.

I want the program to loop and do this for every email in my inbox.

```
import poplib
import string, random
import StringIO, rfc822
import logging
import random

SERVER = "pop.gmail.com"
USER  = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
PASSWORD = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

# connect to server
logging.debug('connecting to ' + SERVER)
server = poplib.POP3_SSL(SERVER)
#server = poplib.POP3(SERVER)

# login
logging.debug('logging in')
server.user(USER)
server.pass_(PASSWORD)

# list items on server
logging.debug('listing emails')
resp, items, octets = server.list()

# download the first message in the list
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
mail.select('inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
mail_ids = data[0]

id_list = mail_ids.split()   
first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
for i in range(latest_email_id, first_email_id, -1):
    id, size = string.split(items[0])
    resp, text, octets = server.retr(id)

# convert list to Message object
    text = string.join(text, "\n")
    file = StringIO.StringIO(text)
    message = rfc822.Message(file)

# output message
    print(message['From']),
    print(message['Subject']),
    print(message['Date']),
#print(message.fp.read()) 
    mynumber = message['Subject']
    myint = int(mynumber)

    print "Let's play a game! I'll choose a number between 0 and 10. Try to guess it!"

    python_number = random.randint(0,10)

    if python_number == myint:
        print "You won! My number was " + str(python_number)
    else:
        print "You loose! My number was " + str(python_number)
```

Comment: put everything after `# download the first message in the list` in a for loop. I believe you should be iterating through `items`

Comment: Can someone tell me what is wrong with my question? I have seen so many basic questions on this site with no effort from the op and they get so many answers and a bunch of up votes?

Comment: @wpercy, I edited my question, am I on the right track?

Comment: I have no idea why this is downvoted. It seems well-presented to me.

Comment: Clicked on this because it was downvoted so much. No idea why it is downvoted - seems like a well written question (although the use case seems a little odd!) Oh well. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @jonathanbell, I want to learn how to read and send emails using python (first time using python) so that's why I am just starting out with reading and sending very basic things so that I can learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is instead of getting the first item

```
id, size = string.split(items[0])
```

you want to get all items:

```
for item in items:
    id, size = string.split(item)
```

And then indent the code following this so it runs for each `item` in `items`

```
import poplib
import string, random
import StringIO, rfc822
import logging
import random

SERVER = "pop.gmail.com"
USER  = "myEmail"
PASSWORD = "myPassword"

# connect to server
logging.debug('connecting to ' + SERVER)
server = poplib.POP3_SSL(SERVER)

# login
logging.debug('logging in')
server.user(USER)
server.pass_(PASSWORD)

# list items on server
logging.debug('listing emails')
resp, items, octets = server.list()

for item in items:
    #For each message
    id, size = string.split(item)
    resp, text, octets = server.retr(id)

    # convert list to Message object
    text = string.join(text, "\n")
    file = StringIO.StringIO(text)
    message = rfc822.Message(file)

    # output message
    print(message['From']),
    print(message['Subject']),
    print(message['Date']),
    #print(message.fp.read()) 
    mynumber = message['Subject']
    myint = int(mynumber)

    print "Let's play a game! I'll choose a number between 0 and 10. Try to guess it!"

    python_number = random.randint(0,10)

    if python_number == myint:
        print "You won! My number was " + str(python_number)
    else:
        print "You loose! My number was " + str(python_number)
```